# Can "study" be used without an object?

Tags: grammar

On the internet I usually see *study* used with objects.  For example:

> I (do) study literature at university.

Can *study* be used **without** an object, as in the following examples?

> I study at the university.
>
> Do you study at the university?

Are these sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: As any dictionary (such as [this one](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/study?q=study)) will tell you, *study* may be used intransitively - see definitions 1.2 and 1.3.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that it wasn't a simple proofreading question, but I agree with StoneyB that this question can be answered by looking at a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study is a verb and can be used transitively or intransitively.

> I study.
>
> I study English.
>
> I study at the university.

You can also add "do" which is also a verb.

> I do study.
>
> I do study English.
>
> I do study at the university.
>
> Do you study at the university? Yes, I do.

All are correct.